# Quokka для Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, extension, visual-studio-extensions

Увидел замечательное расширение в VS Code для JS - Quokka, есть нечто подобное для Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нечто подобное есть: [AREPL for python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=almenon.arepl). Правда, работает не точно также, как Quokka...

- установите расширение
- откройте любой python-файл
- нажмите комбинацию клавиш <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

Появится окошко с выводом и текущими значениями переменных. Данные будут обновляться автоматически во время ввода текста.

Answer (score -1):

upd: Также нашёл расширение wolf! Всем спасибо за ответы!

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]